# No lee la propiedad 'replace'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dentro de mi editor tengo una funcion la cual me deja remplazar un fondo con distintos elementos, dentro de ellos con una imagen. Pero al querer utilizar la opcion de imagen, por consola me figura ***Cannot read property 'replace' of null*** Y aqui coloco la funcion que tengo y donde me tira el error.

```
/**
         * Initializes the UI elements of an specific background tab
         *
         * @param config
         */
        var initializeTab = function(config) {
            var tab = config.type,
                $thumb = $wrapper.find('.thumb-img')
                ;

            // initialize empty
            $thumb.addClass('empty').attr('src', $thumb.data('src-empty'));

            if (tab === 'image') {
                var src = config.value.replace('url(', '').replace(')', '');
                // Handle the case in which an image background is
                // configured but no image is selected
                src ? $thumb.removeClass("empty") : $thumb.addClass('empty');
                $thumb.attr("src", src || $thumb.data('src-empty'));

                var $imagePositionSelector = $wrapper.find('#image-position');
                $imagePositionSelector.val(config.extra);
                $imagePositionSelector.trigger("liszt:updated");
            }
            var $applyMobileSelector = $wrapper.find(options.apply_mobile_selector);
            if (config.alternate === 'bkgnd-normal') {
                $applyMobileSelector.attr('checked', 'checked');
            } else {
                $applyMobileSelector.removeAttr('checked');
            }
        };
        /**
         * Resets the UI elements to reflect the current configuration
         *
         * @param tab
         */
        var resetTabConfiguration = function(tab) {
            var $imagePositionSelector = $wrapper.find('#image-position');
            /** HACK: Forcefully reset chosen selection for image background position.
             * This is done in order to have a clean start with the select when moving
             * from another configuration, such as 'pattern' or 'color'.
             * */
            if (tab !== 'imagen') {
                $wrapper.find('#image_position_chzn').remove();
                $imagePositionSelector.val('').removeClass('chzn-done').chosen();
            }

            var config = service.getConfiguration();
            switch (config.type) {
                case 'pattern':
                    $wrapper.find('.pattern-library li').removeClass('selected');
                    $wrapper.find('.' + config.extra.replace(' ', '.')).addClass('selected');
                    $wrapper.find('.btn-picker-pattern').css({'background-color': config.color});
                    break;
                case 'color':
                    $wrapper.find('.btn-picker-color').css({'background-color': config.color});
                    break;
                case 'image':
                    $wrapper.find('#image_position_chzn').remove();
                    $imagePositionSelector.val(config.extra).removeClass('chzn-done').chosen();
                    break;
            }
            $('body').trigger('menu-configuration-update');
        };
        /**
         * Initializes the tabs for the different background types (pattern, color and image)
         */
        var initializeTabs = function() {
            /**
             * Shows a background config tab
             *
             * @param tab
             */
            var showBackgroundTab = function(tab) {
                var map = {
                    none    : '',
                    color  : '.tab_solido',
                    pattern : '.tab_pattern',
                    image  : '.tab_img'
                };
                if (tab !== 'none' && !map[tab]) {
                    throw 'Background tab `' + tab + '` not found';
                }

                $wrapper.find('.tab_edit').hide();
                $wrapper.find(map[tab]).show();

                if (tab === 'none') {
                    service.resetConfiguration();
                }

                resetTabConfiguration(tab);
            };

            /**
             * Updates the combo/select box to select an specific background type
             *
             * @param type The type to select: none, color, pattern, image
             */
            var selectBackgroundType = function(type) {
                var map = {
                    none    : 'none',
                    color   : 'solido',
                    pattern : 'pattern',
                    image   : 'imagen'
                };
                if (!map[type]) {
                    throw 'Background type `' + type + '` not found';
                }
                $backgroundTypeSelector.removeClass('active').filter('[data-type="' + type + '"]').addClass('active');

                showBackgroundTab(type);
                $('body').trigger('menu-configuration-update');
            };

            $backgroundTypeSelector.off('click').on('click', function(e) {
                var $target = $(e.target).hasClass('item') ? $(e.target) : $(e.target).parents('.item'),
                    type = $target.data('type')
                    ;
                selectBackgroundType(type);
                showBackgroundTab(type);

                // This setTimeout is due to a race condition between the click event on $backgroundTypeSelector
                // and spectrum plugin; the former was fired first causing the correct background type to be
                // applied, the latter caused the previous background type to be shown to the user (throught
                // the function "updateBackgroundColor" on themeConfigurationHelper)
                var handler = setTimeout(function () {
                    setConfiguration(type);
                    clearTimeout(handler);
                }, 100);
            });

            /**
             * Show tab for current configuration
             */
            var selectedTab = service.getConfiguration().type;
            /**
             * If the current tab is `none` for `site` then force it to `color`
             * as `site` configuration doesn't have a `none` tab or configuration.
             */
            if (service.getTargetType() === 'site' && selectedTab === 'none') {
                selectedTab = 'color';
            }

            selectBackgroundType(selectedTab);
            initializeTab(service.getConfiguration());
        };
```

fijense que en `$wrapper.find('.' + config.extra.replace(' ', '.')).addClass('selected');` tengo uno de los errores que no reconoce ese replace que esta con config.extra.

tambien tengo la variable **SRC** que esta en el initializeTab al principio de la funcion que les muestro que contiene ese replace

```
var src = config.value.replace('url(', '').replace(')', '');
```

Como soluciono el error?

Comment: podrias agregar los datos de config ? porque parece que "config.extra" no està definido

Comment: var config = service.getConfiguration(); tengo eso en la funcion como config @Federico y sobre extra lo siguiente:  @param extra Extra configuration such as `background-repeat`

Comment: eso es porque `config.extra` esta vacio, lo que te puedo decir por ahora es que le metas una condición adelante ejemplo : `if (!$.isEmptyObject(config.extra)) { $wrapper.find('.' + config.extra.replace(' ', '.')).addClass('selected');` asi te aseguras que tenga algo al interno antes de lanzar el replace si no lo evita. sin saber de donde viene la configuración es dificil de enternder :(